# Django migrate command resulting in foreign key mismatch error

Tags: python, django, database

Django----sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "socialnetworkapp_chat" referencing "socialnetworkapp_chatroom"

i have been getting error from doing performing a python manage.py migrate command, for further context i have tried reverting the migration to the previous migration where everything works fine, but after altering a few models i keep on getting this error

below is the code i have in my models.py

```
`
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    chatroom_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Chat(models.Model):
    chat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    chat_content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    chatroom = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
```

after this migration, even when i delete these models just to see if the error would resolved, the error still persists in appearing, can anyone help me detect the issue. If more context on my code is required feel free to ask, thank you.